# storing the path to a setter method so that it can be called later

Tags: java

```
 public class TopLevelObject{

    List<SecondLevelObject> secondLevelObjects;
    Long field;
```

}

```
public class SecondLevelObject{
    List<ThirdLevelObject> thirdLevelObjects;
    Long field;
```

}

```
public class ThirdLevelObject{
     Long field1;
     Long field2;
```

}

We have a TopLevelObject, which contains a list of SecondLevelObjects, all of which contain list of ThirdLevelObjects

We need to initialize some fields of this structure initially by iterating through it, and postpone initializing the others, but avoid iterating it all over again

So is it possible to store references/path to the setters of that field to call them later? (Assuming you can know which setter to call when)

Comment: When you stop and continue iterating over it is like we iterate over logical half the elements and then stop i.e. 1..n/2 or is it like lets choose certain elements. Also when you go back to iterating over the elements would the collection change inbetween?

Comment: If you need to initialize multiple objects, I fail to see how you could do it without iterating, there's no magic there. Either you do it, or some framework does it for you, but in the end it's still a loop.

Comment: @Brad no, we don't stop halfway, no the collection(s) wouldnt change

Comment: @Frank yeah, but instead of doing top.getsecondlist().get(0).getthirdlist.get(0).setfield(), you can just call that particular setfield directly if you could store it as a value in a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, is this just a matter of performance? Because if so, come back when you've measured it.

Second, check you're not being too clever. Read up about the Inner Platform effect. Do you *really* need to hand-roll this lazy initialization code, or can you use JPA or something else?

If you're still sure, you can use a custom object that defers the setting like this

```
// [some code that is about to set the property on thirdLevelObject
Runnable deferredSetter = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         thirdLevelObject.setFoo(/* wherever the value for foo comes from later */);
    }
}
```

These deferred setter `Runnable`s can be added to a collection that you would loop through during the later initialization. But I still think you can avoid this approach by simplifying your design.

Comment: Well said! Indeed, I think I could perhaps use a Map to avoid this. +1 to the technique though. And does run() take arguments?

Comment: @cee_el run() does not, but the anonymous class can capture variables from the enclosing method if they are final.

Comment: @FrankPavageau couldn't have put it better. @cee_el you can use a custom class instead of `Runnable`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice better to use [**Apache BeanUtils.PropertyUtils**](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) to call the setter based on the path when you need that. Some use methods are list below:

```
PropertyUtils.setProperty(Object bean, String propertyName, Object value)  
PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(Object bean, String propertyName, Object value)   
PropertyUtils.setIndexedProperty(Object bean, String propertyName, int index, 
                                 Object value) 
PropertyUtils.setIndexedProperty(Object bean, String propertyName, Object value)
```

Comment: so for the first argument, I need to have a reference to the ThirdLevelObject instance that I want to modify, and would it be THAT instance itself which would be modified, or a copy of it, since Java is not pass by reference...

Comment: Yes, you can mention the path of any level objects. It will traverse and call the setter method as appropriate. You are passing the parent object to be modified as the first parameter in the methods. That object or any child objects as mentioned in the path will be modified.

Comment: First argument is your FirstLevel object always. It's the path of the attribute metioned there after makes the difference e.g. `seondobject[0].thidobject[1].fieldname` to update first second object1 second third objects, fieldname field.